# Backbonejs collection.fetch() not working: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined

Tags: backbone.js

When executing collection.fetch() the following error is being produced

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
    Backbone.Events.triggerbackbone-0.5.3.js:117
    _.extend._onModelEventbackbone-0.5.3.js:635
    Backbone.Events.triggerbackbone-0.5.3.js:117
    _.extend._addbackbone-0.5.3.js:595
    _.extend.addbackbone-0.5.3.js:448
    _.extend.fetch.options.successbackbone-0.5.3.js:521
    jQuery.Callbacks.firejquery.js:1064
    jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWithjquery.js:1182
    donejquery.js:7454
    jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callbackjquery.js:8235
```

The response from the server

```
[
  {"title":"The Ampersand Collection","id":"4f1deca441c41f9700000014"},
  {"title":"The Ampersand Collection2","id":"4f1deca441c41f9700000014"},
  {"title":"The Ampersand Collection3","id":"4f1deca441c41f9700000014"},
  //...
]
```

Code

```
  $feed.animate({scrollLeft: $(event.target).hasClass('left') ? '-=' + win_width : '+=' + win_width}, {
    step: function(){
      if(!loaded && scope.model.feedlets.last().view !== undefined && !$.rightoffold(scope.model.feedlets.last().view.el, {container: $(scope.model.feedlets.last().view.el).parent(), threshold: 400})) {
        loaded = true;
        scope.model.feedlets.fetch({
          add:true,
          data: {
            limit: 20,
            offset: scope.model.feedlets.models.length
          },
          success: function() {
            console.log(scope.model.feedlets.models);
          }
        });
      }
    },
    complete: function(){
      $('#container').triggerHandler('scroll');
    }
  });
```

*scope* is an instance of **FeedView** which model is an instance of **FeedModel**. I am using nested collections so each **FeedModel** has a collection of **Feedlets**.

Comment: Can you provide the code in which you call `...collection.fetch()`?

Comment: I added the code. This is a function in a view which is executed on an event.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the error trace, somewhere in your view you seem to have called `bind` on the collection's "add" event with an undefined function.  So look for something like this within the view:

```
mycollection.bind('add', this.func, this);
```

In your code, `this.func` (whatever it really is) seems to be undefined, or at least it's not a function.  Maybe you tried to bind a function before it was created?  I'm not sure without seeing the full view code.

Comment: This is exactly what it was. I had bound an all event on the render function.